# calling javascript objective-c without visible uiwebview

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to call javascript functions from my objective-c. This for iphone. I understand how the call to the javascript function is done with this line

```
NSString *returnValue = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:method];
```

But I dont actually want a webview to be seen or used as part of the UI. So can I just create an instance of it right before calling the method above in some way.

I have tried:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[webView loadRequest:[NSUrLRequest requestWithUrl:url]];
```

but nothing seems to happen. So is there a method similar to the above that I am meant to use.

Comment: Adding it to the view is not the main issue. See my answer for the full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the webview in your controller's view in order to run the javascript. it won't be visible since it has zero height and width.

Comment: I added it to the view before thinking something like that would happen but I got the error "application windows are expected to have a root view controller"

Comment: where did you try to add it? you should do this inside a view controller. [self addSubview:web view];

Comment: I must have done something wrong earlier as I tried it again and it worked this time. So thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry slight follow up question but my returnValue is not taking a NSString as the result. Do you know why this might be?? In the console it says @<variable is not NSString>

Comment: Return Value:
The result of running script or nil if it fails. Cross check it. it might be nil.

Comment: returnValue has just become a blank string @"" I assume because it couldnt process what was returned which I dont understand.

Comment: mistake was in the javascript, thanks for the help, very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to the size of the `UIWebView`. It is simply a timing issue. The following code works as desired with a zero rect `UIWebView` instance. Note the use of `UIWebViewDelegate` method `webViewDidFinishLoad:`. `UIWebView` is slow and it takes time for the view to load its content and be prepared to accept JavaScript commands.

```
@interface NGViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *hiddenWebView;
@end

@implementation NGViewController

@synthesize hiddenWebView = _hiddenWebView;

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

  if (!self.hiddenWebView.superview)
  {
    [self.view addSubview:self.hiddenWebView];
  }
}

- (UIWebView *)hiddenWebView
{
  if (!_hiddenWebView) {
    _hiddenWebView = [UIWebView.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _hiddenWebView.delegate = self;
    [_hiddenWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><head><script>window.james = 'My name';</script></head><body><h1>Hidden Web View by James</h1></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
  }
  return _hiddenWebView;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  NSString *documentBodyString = [self.hiddenWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.james;"];
  NSLog(@"The body's inner HTML is: %@", documentBodyString);
}

@end
```

The output of which is:

```
2013-07-09 03:13:29.347 WebViewTest[14261:c07] The body's inner HTML is: My name
```

Comment: cannot I not just use webViewDidFinishLoad instead of manually delaying??

Comment: @walsh06 — did you try it? The point is you have a timing issue, and I've provided you with a working example. I've updated the answer to show that delegate method also works.